# SQLiteOpenHelper NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite

I have another post here that is similar to this one, however, i have made some changes to my classes and having a different issue now. The previous issue was also never resolved.

My application needs to be able to write to the sqlite3 database that is on the android from 2 different events. One of my events is writing to the database just fine. When the second event tries to write to the database the attached error occurs.

I am unable to resolve this issue. I have been looking at this for over a week. Any help is greatly appreciated. If any other information is needed, PLEASE let me know! I will post everything i have as long as i can get this issue resolved, it is stressing me out.

```
The Error Logcat
03-22 23:50:27.065: INFO/System.out(281): Where: DB-submitData
03-22 23:50:30.846: WARN/System.err(281): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 23:50:30.865: WARN/System.err(281):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
03-22 23:50:30.865: WARN/System.err(281):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
03-22 23:50:30.875: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartDBHelper.open(SmartDBHelper.java:70)
03-22 23:50:30.875: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataBuilder.submitData(DataBuilder.java:37)
03-22 23:50:30.884: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataBuilder.prepareData(DataBuilder.java:29)
03-22 23:50:30.904: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp$2.dataAnalyzedReceived(SmartApp.java:56)
03-22 23:50:30.904: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataRobot.fireDataAnalyzedEvent(DataRobot.java:269)
03-22 23:50:30.916: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.DataRobot.analyzeData(DataRobot.java:79)
03-22 23:50:30.925: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.SmartApp$1.dataReceivedReceived(SmartApp.java:49)
03-22 23:50:30.935: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.ConnectDevice.fireDataReceivedEvent(ConnectDevice.java:79)
03-22 23:50:30.945: WARN/System.err(281):     at cpe495.smartapp.ConnectDevice.run(ConnectDevice.java:46)
03-22 23:50:30.945: WARN/System.err(281):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

---

```
//The main class SmartApp.java
public class SmartApp extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    TextView smartConnectionStatus;
    TextView testOutputView;
    Thread cThread;
    private ConnectDevice cD = new ConnectDevice();
    private DataRobot dR = new DataRobot(this);
    private DataBuilder dB = new DataBuilder();
    private DataSender dS = new DataSender(this);

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);

        cD.addDataReceivedListener(new DataReceivedListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataReceivedReceived(DataReceivedEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dR.analyzeData(event.getData());
            }
        });
        dR.addDataAnalyzedListener(new DataAnalyzedListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataAnalyzedReceived(DataAnalyzedEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dB.prepareData(event.getData());
            }
        });
        dR.addDataAlertListener(new DataAlertListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataAlertReceived(DataAlertEvent event) {
                Log.v("SmartApp", "data alert event caught");
                DataAlert a = new DataAlert(SmartApp.this);
                mHandler.post(a);
            }
        });
        dR.addDataNotifyListener(new DataNotifyListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataNotifyReceived(DataNotifyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("SmartApp", "data notification event caught");
                DataNotification a = new DataNotification(SmartApp.this);
                mHandler.post(a);
            }
        });
        dB.addDataBuilderListener(new DataBuilderListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataBuilderReceived(DataBuilderEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dS.sendData(event.getData());
            }
        });
    }
    private Context getContext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
//The DataBuilder.java class that fails to access the database
public class DataBuilder extends Activity {
    private List _listeners = new ArrayList();
    private SmartDataObject data;
    SmartDBHelper sDBH = new SmartDBHelper(this);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("databuilder", "on create");
    }

    public void prepareData(SmartDataObject temp) {
        submitData(temp);
    }

    public void submitData(SmartDataObject temp) {
        data = temp;
        System.out.println("Where: DB-submitData");
        try {
            sDBH.open();
            sDBH.insertDataResponse(data.getHeartRate(), data.getAct(), data.getTimeStamp());
            sDBH.close();
            fireDataBuilderEvent(data);
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void addDataBuilderListener(DataBuilderListener listener) {
        _listeners.add(listener);
    }
    public synchronized void removeDataBuilderListener(DataBuilderListener listener) {
        _listeners.remove(listener);
    }
    private synchronized void fireDataBuilderEvent(SmartDataObject temp) {
        DataBuilderEvent dRE = new DataBuilderEvent(this, temp);
        Iterator listeners = _listeners.iterator();
        while(listeners.hasNext()) {
            ((DataBuilderListener)listeners.next()).dataBuilderReceived(dRE);
        }
    }
    public interface DataBuilderListener {
        public void dataBuilderReceived(DataBuilderEvent event);
    }
}
```

---

```
//The DataNotificationSurvey.java class that access the database successfully.
public class DataNotificationSurvey extends Activity {
    private Date timeStamp;
    private Uri mUri;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.datanotificationlayout);
        Log.v("datanotificationsurvey", "inside datanotificationsurvey");


        timeStamp = new Date(DataNotification.when);

        TextView notifyDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notifyDateTV);
        notifyDate.setText(timeStamp.toLocaleString());
        final Button notifySubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notifySubmitButton);
        final RadioButton patientCrisisRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.patientCrisis);
        final RadioButton physicalActivityRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.physicalActivity);

        notifySubmitButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(patientCrisisRB.isChecked()) {
                            submitNotify(1, timeStamp);
                        }
                        else if(physicalActivityRB.isChecked()) {
                            submitNotify(2, timeStamp);
                        }
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }

    public void submitNotify(int tempType, Date tempDate) {
        SmartDBHelper sDBH = new SmartDBHelper(this);
        sDBH.open();
        sDBH.insertNotificationResponse(tempType, tempDate);
        sDBH.close();
        /*ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("userresponse", tempType);
        values.put("notifytime", (tempDate.getTime()/1000));
        mUri = getContentResolver().insert(intent.getData(), values);*/
    }
}
```

---

```
//The SQLiteOpenHelper class, it extends this DatabaseHelper.
public class SmartDBHelper extends Activity {

    private DatabaseHelper dBH;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context mCtx;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "smart_lite_db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String NOTIFY_TABLE_NAME = "user_notify_data";
    private static final String HR_TABLE_NAME = "user_hr_data";
    private static final String NOTIFY_TABLE_CREATE = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + NOTIFY_TABLE_NAME + 
        " (counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
        "userresponse INTEGER, " + 
        "notifytime INTEGER);";
    private static final String DATA_TABLE_CREATE = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + HR_TABLE_NAME +
        " (counter INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        "hr INTEGER, " +
        "act INTEGER, " +
        "timestamp INTEGER);";

    static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("smartdbhelper", "before creation");
            db.execSQL(NOTIFY_TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.v("smartdbhelper", "middle creation");
            db.execSQL(DATA_TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.v("smartdbhelper", "after creation");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    public SmartDBHelper(Context context) {
        this.mCtx = context;
    }

    public SmartDBHelper open() throws SQLException {
        dBH = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        db = dBH.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dBH.close();
    }

    public long insertNotificationResponse(int tempType, Date tempDate) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("userresponse", tempType);
        values.put("notifytime", (tempDate.getTime()/1000));
        return db.insert(NOTIFY_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public long insertDataResponse(double tempAct, int tempHR, long tempDate) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("hr", tempHR);
        values.put("act", tempAct);
        values.put("timestamp", (tempDate/1000));
        return db.insert(HR_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't accept answers that aren't actually answers.  You force people to read through the list of comments to find out that it's not actually the answer.

Comment: Voting to close. As it is too localized and will not help future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is an old question, but its accepted answer is wrong and the author can't delete the whole thing so for the sake of future visitors here is the answer.*

In DataBuilder you are passing the Context before it has been initialized to SmartDBHelper's constructor.

```
SmartDBHelper sDBH = new SmartDBHelper(this);
```

You must wait until the `onCreate()` to access a valid Context:

```
public class DataBuilder extends Activity {
    private List _listeners = new ArrayList();
    private SmartDataObject data;
    SmartDBHelper sDBH;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("databuilder", "on create");
        sDBH = new SmartDBHelper(this);
    }

    // Rest of class
}
```

Also I don't believe DataBuilder or SmartDBHelper should extend Activity. They don't use any of Activity's methods and you cannot start an Activity by calling `new DataBulder()`:

```
public class DataBuidler {

public class SmartDBHelper {
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98   is   db = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(mName, 0, mFactory);

so you set a null context in SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: thats right. It was a problem in my case and same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183234/getwritabledatabase-throwing-null-pointer-exception

Answer (score 0):

You DatabaseHelper class is defined as static. That is causing all the problem. When a nested class is declared as static it doesnt have access to instance variables and method of the enclosing class

More Details read [Nested Class in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: I get the same result when the DatabaseHelper class is not static. I have already tested that, i changed to static, because someone suggested i try that a few days ago.

Comment: In that case I am not sure. Can you check if dBH is null before calling getWritableDatabase method

Comment: I have tested this, did this every time i made changes that were said to fix the problem. The way listed above, dBH is not null before calling getWritableDatabase. But other implementations it is null.

Comment: This did not fix the problem, however, i am going to accept as the answer since this person attempted to assist me. I have found an alternative method for what i am trying to do, so resolving this problem is not crucial anymore. If someone posts something that will solve the problem in the future, i will change the accepted answer.