# getWritableDatabase() throwing null pointer exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a service class having following code -

```
public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService{      
    private static final String TAG ="ReminderService";
    private TasksDBAdapter dbHelper;
    public ReminderService(){
        super("ReminderService");
        dbHelper = new TasksDBAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open(); //THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
    }
```

code for TasksDBAdapter open() method is as -

```
    public TasksDBAdapter(Context ctx) {                                 
       this.mCtx = ctx;
   }

    public TasksDBAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException {
           mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
           Log.i(TAG, "mDbHelper in open method-->" + mDbHelper);
           mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // ACTUAL ERROR LINE
           return this;
       }
```

the log value receives address which means mDbHelper gets initialized properly.Log.i gives -

```
11-01 23:32:32.004: I/TasksDBAdapter(681): mDbHelper in open method-->ray.kaushik.simple.task.manager.TasksDBAdapter$DatabaseHelper@411e7a10
```

but

```
mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

throws the null pointer error.

Logcat gives -

```
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service ray.kaushik.simple.task.manager.ReminderService: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2347)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at ray.kaushik.simple.task.manager.TasksDBAdapter.open(TasksDBAdapter.java:38)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at ray.kaushik.simple.task.manager.ReminderService.<init>(ReminderService.java:16)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2344)
11-01 23:32:32.043: E/AndroidRuntime(681):  ... 10 more
```

My databaseHelper class code  -

```
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {          
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);      
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {                       
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);                                
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {                                   

        }
    }
```

where DATABASE_NAME and all others have been defined globally -

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";              
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "reminders";        
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;                   

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";                  
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time"; 
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";                    
    private static final String TAG = "TasksDBAdapter";
```

can anyone please provide some pointers.. thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: Please post your LogCat errors and your `Log.i()` line.

Comment: I don't know about DatabaseHelper. What I do in my app is to make a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Then I override the methods I need. Have you looked at SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: Are you providing a name for your database? Please post your DatabaseHelper constructor.

Comment: i have addded DatabaseHelper class which is basically one inner class to TasksDBAdapter class.

Comment: i have kind of resolved it but can not post details before 8 hours as my reputation is below 10 currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the IntentService hasn't been fully initialized when you try to create the database in the constructor. Try moving your code into `onHandleIntent()`:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    dbHelper = new TasksDBAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Yes thts d same i did.. I was having another overridden function in ReminderService class in which i moved the open() method and it worked. I just can not answer my question before 8 hours.

Comment: can you please explain it a little more as I am new to android and didnt exactly get the issue.what happens when i call it from constructor.?

Comment: (I gave you an upvote, so now you're at 10 rep!) I quickly found _why_ the NullPointerException is thrown, you can read the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String%2Cint%2Candroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%2Candroid.database.DatabaseErrorHandler%29) from your LogCat. But it took me awhile to find _where_ `mBase` is initialized. This only happens after the IntentService is attached to the current Context (later on).

Answer (score 0):

I kinda resolved the issue -

I have the class ReminderService  where I was trying to call the dbHelper.open(); method.

Also this same class have one overridden method doReminderWork(intent) , where I was going to use the dbHelper initialized.

Earlier code -

```
  public ReminderService(){
            super("ReminderService");
            dbHelper = new TasksDBAdapter(this);
            dbHelper.open(); //THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
        }

    @Override
        void doReminderWork(Intent intent){ 

    /**
              * retrieve data about task
              */

             Cursor reminder = dbHelper.fetchReminder(rowId);
   }
```

in which i moved the open method in doReminderWork(Intent intent) method like -

```
public ReminderService(){
                super("ReminderService");
                dbHelper = new TasksDBAdapter(this);

            }

        @Override
            void doReminderWork(Intent intent){ 

        /**
                  * retrieve data about task
                  */
                dbHelper.open(); //MOVED HERE
                 Cursor reminder = dbHelper.fetchReminder(rowId);
       }
```

and it worked.. Can anyone give me proper detailed explanation why this worked as it was just a try that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of actions must be called from a separate thread, Try to call it with a Thread object or AsyncTask.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        dbHelper.open(); //MOVED HERE
        Cursor reminder = dbHelper.fetchReminder(rowId);
    }
});
t.start();
```